# How to build(gradle) .deb and .exe from java application developed with openJavaFx 11

Tags: gradle, exe, deb, openjfx, openjdk-11

I'm developing a javafx application using,

- gradle
- OpenJdk11
- OpenJfx11
- sqlite (It also stored inside main package as sqlite.db)

Now I need to build .deb file for ubuntu installation and .exe file for window installation

build.gradle here

```
plugins {
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'war'

    group = 'dmhashan'

mainClassName = 'dmhashan.payroll.AppStarter'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx:14-ea+2'
    implementation 'com.1stleg:jnativehook:2.0.2'
    implementation 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.5.0'
    implementation 'net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:5.5.0'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:5.1'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-jdbc:5.1'
    implementation 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.23.1'
    providedCompile 'com.konghq:unirest-java:3.7.02'
    implementation 'com.konghq:unirest-object-mappers-gson:3.7.02'
}

javafx {
    version = "11.0.2"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.graphics' ]
}

run() {
    jvmArgs = ['--add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application=ALL-UNNAMED']
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With just Gradle you can only build an executable JAR that can run on Windows and Linux. To bundle it into an exe or a deb package, you'll need some Gradle plugins.

For the exe, you can use [gradle-launch4j](https://github.com/TheBoegl/gradle-launch4j).

For the deb, you can sue [gradle-ospackage-plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin). You find the documentation [here](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin/wiki/Deb-Plugin).

Comment: could you please help me how I need to change above build.gradle for build fat jar (jar file with all libraries and fxml files), plz?

Comment: Maybe this works for you: https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin#minimal-setup-of-buildgradle